# htaccess file working fine on local but on server error

Tags: .htaccess

This is my url http://www.example.com/demo/
what's wrong with my htaccess file? and how to slove it?
thank you in advance

```
#CHECK MOD REWRITE ON IN HOSTING SERVER
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#REWRITE URL FOR ALL PHP FILE TO HTML
RewriteBase /demo/

RewriteRule ^home\.html$ index.php?page=$1&lang=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^h([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.\/]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.\/]+)\.html$ index.php?page=$1&lang=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^p([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.\/]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.\/]+)\.html$ product.php?page=$1&lang=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^s([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.\/]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.\/]+)\.html$ service.php?page=$1&lang=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^a([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.\/]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.\/]+)\.html$ about.php?page=$1&lang=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^c([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.\/]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.\/]+)\.html$ contact.php?page=$1&lang=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Are you sure that your live server allows overriding Apache directives?

Comment: i got internal server error while accessing it